# Can I carry milk on board for a toddler on a flight from Toronto to Saudi Airline?

Tags: canada, children, airport-security, saudi-airlines

I was reading the contents of the website (Saudi Airline) that we could carry milk up to 1 litre in a transparent bag for babies.

My wife tried formula for my 2 year old kid but he's refusing to take it, he's only taking homo milk, so, according to their website: we might take 1 litre of milk in transparent bag with us in aircraft. Will I have any problems doing this?

Comment: Nadeem, is it ok for your kid to have "Pasteurized Homogenized Milk" like the ones in supermarkets?

Comment: [This is the exact milk product](http://almarai.com/en/our-products/dairy-liquids/fresh_milk/) (whole milk) that can be found on all international flights for Saudi Airlines (Saudia). Perhaps your son can have that so you do not have to worry about bringing your own. Anyway, an equivalent products might be available in flights departing from airports out of Saudi Arabia.

Comment: @gagravarr I have edit the post to include "Saudia" tag which is the name for Saudi Airlines, I did not mean to include "saudi-Arabia" tag as you suggested.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question, but pasteurized homogenized milk is generally considered very bad for infants. (It is often considered bad for adults, too, but with less dire and acute affects)

Comment: @Flimzy 2 years is not an [infant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infant). Infants are from 1 to 12 months old.

Comment: @MeNoTalk: Well, generally only "infants" need special milk...

Comment: @Flimzy true, but "homo" milk if I get it right is the milk we buy in groceries, right? 2 years old can drink it, but the main food source for them should be the solid food. The question makes you think we are talking about special infants milk, while I guess it is generally about normal milk. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MeNoTalk: They can drink it... but they shouldn't (normally) need special milk on a flight... I guess it's just a weird question.

Answer (score 3):

From the [CATSA website](http://www.catsa.gc.ca/liquids-food-personal-items):

[image]

Note the "**declare the items for inspection**". They will likely want to do further checking on the milk (ie. open the container, do swabs, and so on) to make sure it's not something harmful. It should also be not more than an appropriate amount for the length of the trip.

Comment: But the thing is I'm not bringing into Canada but from Canada to Saudi Arabia.

Comment: CATSA are the ones who will do the inspection at the security checkpoint in Toronto.

Answer (score 2):

You have three issues:

1. Can you get it through the security checkpoint in Pearson, or buy it after security in Pearson? If the child is **less than 24 months** you can bring it through security, and it doesn't need to be in a clear bag either. I think small milk cartons are your best bet - 250 ml, 500 ml, 1 L as you think you need them. At Pearson I'm pretty sure you could buy them after security also, but it might be stressful to look for them. If your child is over 24 months, that will be your only choice however. Don't try to bring a clear 1-quart bag of milk from home, that's going to be awful to deal with on the plane.
2. Is it ok to have it on the plane? Yes. But how will you keep it cold? Wouldn't it be better to bring a small amount for in the airport, and let the airline give you more on board as you need it?
3. Can you bring it in to SA? That's a good question, and unless you intend to use it all up in flight, one you need to consider. Most places frown on food and agricultural products coming into the country. And depending on how long you're staying, there's no way you can bring enough (unrefrigerated, too) with you to last your whole trip, so you're going to need to figure out how to get milk for the baby while you're there, right?

In your shoes, I would bring 2 250ml cartons, and keep them both sealed until after security. (If you have some sort of toddler issue before security, you can use one and still have the other, then keep an eye out for a chance to buy a replacement.) Use one during the time before you board, and bring one onto the plane. Save it though, and ask for whatever they have on board. If the toddler likes that you're all set, and if not you have your own. Throw out any opened cartons on leaving the plane, before customs. And start looking now into where to get 3.5% (what we call homo or whole milk) there. (The link from MeNoTalk shows a brand and that they call it full-fat. You might want to print that page so as to have the pictures to show hotel staff.)